# Centering a div inside a flex item

Tags: css, flexbox

**I've checked similar posts and they are not helping.**

I want my innermost div to appear in the center of the parent div.

For example:

```
<container>
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child">
    </div>
  </div>
</container>
```

The parent div is a flex item inside an inline-flex container. `margin: 0 auto` is only allowing it to horizontally align, but I need it vertically aligned as well. Height and width are 80% of parent div.

How do I go about this?

Also, I will need to add a `display: none` at times. When I don't want `display: none` active, what can I leave display as?

Edit:

```
.Card {
    width: 150px;
    height: 220px;
    border: 2px solid rgb(218, 186, 186);
    margin: 10px;
    display: inline-flex;
}

.FaceUp {
    display: none;
}

.FaceDown {
    height: 80%;
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
```

I've tried margin, justify-content, justify-items, align-content, align-items, vertical-align. None seem to be working.

FaceDown and FaceUp will never display at the same time. They are the child/sibling divs inside the parent div.

Comment: vertical-align:middle?

Comment: Add your code what you have tried or jsfiddle

Comment: alignment with flex is done with justify-content: center and align-content: center; which of these would be vertical center will be based on your flex-direction.

Comment: These "similar" posts are not similar because they are about the position of the parent/middle div - not the inner most child...

Comment: try `margin: auto;`. the `margin` property has been updated/rewritten to ‘play nicely’ with the flexbox and css grid layout modules.

Answer (score 1):

Did u try writing:

```
 parentDiv {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-content: center;
 }

 childDiv {
  align-self: center;
 }
```

Because every parent should have `display: flex;` in order to affect a child

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
transform: translateY(-50%)
```